# How do I add a list of possible values to a swagger doc?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

Suppose I have the following route:

````
paths:
  /data:
    get:
      summary: Get list of securities based on filter
      parameters:
        - name: market
          in: query
          description: Filter securities by market id, default ```all```
          type: string
          default: all
````

How can I add to this, a list of values that can be used?

Is this even supported? I see an `enum` field but I keep getting errors when adding to any param.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enum` is the way to go. You can specify a list of values under `enum` for parameter and property. Following is a an example:

````
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: Simple API
paths:
  /data:
    get:
      summary: Get list of securities based on filter
      parameters:
        - name: market
          in: query
          description: Filter securities by market id, default ```all```
          type: string
          default: all
          enum:
          - all
          - market1
          - market2
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
````

You can copy and paste above to swagger-editor to see the output.

Comment: of course it would work when someone else posts it =/ btw, i thought when i do enum, it should show on the UI?

Comment: yes, swagger-editor and swagger-ui both support `enum`, and the list of values will be shown in those tools.